# 32 bit registers act as 8 bit ones

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I've been having the strangest problem. In x86 assembly, the 32 bit registers (eax, ebx, etc.) have been overflowing at 256, suggesting that they're actually 8 bit, for some reason. For example:

test.s:

```
section .data
section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 256
    int 80h
```

If I then compile this code with `nasm -felf32 -g test.s && ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test test.s`, and run the resulting executable, it returns 0. This same problem happens for eax, ecx, edx, etc.

Why would the 32 bit registers act like 8 bit ones, in ANY situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the *register* wrapping around, it's the `exit` system call, which only uses the lower eight bits of `ebx` for the return code.

From the `exit` man-page:

> The `exit()` function causes normal process termination and the value of `status & 0377` is returned to the parent (see `wait(2)`).

That `0377` is the octal equivalent of `0xff` (binary `1111 1111`), meaning that only the lower eight bits are used. The other bits in what you get back from `wait()` (in the parent) are used for things such as whether the child process was terminated, what signal was used if so, whether a core dump occurred, and so on.